# Running Shell script from ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, shell

I would like to create a web application (ASP.NET) which needs to execute the shell script from UNIX environment and it should return the output. this web application will be hosted in windows IIS only. Please advice me.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Share the code snippets you have tried yet.
http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18773/Run-Interactive-Command-Shell-or-Batch-Files-From